Atp as energy currency
I have seen that ATP and sometimes GTP is used to deliver energy to reactions in the cell. What is the reason that no other chemical is used for the purpose ? What is the charistiristics of the structure of atp( the nuclear base part , the Penrose part and the tryphosphate part) and its bonds that makes it a perfect energy currency in cells?

Maybe a dupe? https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/81417/why-is-atp-used-as-a-source-of-energy-rather-than-glucose, probably relevant either way

Well this actually doesn't answer . It only compares atp with glucose and not focus on all parts of atp structure .

This question has already been asked and answered: Why is ATP the preferred choice for energy carriers?

This question should be closed as a duplicate, but please proof-read your questions in future. Most web browsers include spelling checkers, and if your computer is set to some language other than English, it should be possible to change it temporarily. If you have done any research on the topic you will surely have noticed that ATP is an acronym and is always capitalized. In addition, your question makes the unjustified and unjustifiable assumptions that ATP is "the perfect energy currency", and shows no evidence that you have tried to research this topic yourself.
